# How will Windows System Restore affect GRUB boot loader?

Tags: windows, windows-10, grub, bootloader, system-restore

I have Windows 10 dual booting with Linux using GRUB.

I have forgotten my Windows administrator password so am hoping that booting into Window's advanced options and doing a "System Restore" will revert it to factory settings (before I gave a password).

If I do this, will the GRUB bootloader be affected?

Comment: System Restore isn't required to recover/reset the password set - there's a multitude of DOS utilities you can boot to that can pull every user password out of the PC, as well as allow you to change the password. The original Hiren's Boot CD allowed you to select the DOS tool you wanted and booted to it, whereas I haven't used the [new PE version](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) of it to know if that same utility is included within. If the password is for the built-in `Administrator` account, simply boot to WinRE, and when the terminal loads: `net user administrator /active: no`

Comment: Also, if the password is for a *local* account, resetting it is trivial (unless BitLocker was used), but if you log in *via* Microsoft see: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-reset-a-forgotten-windows-10-password .

Answer (score 0):

System Restore is an operation that in a nutshell just copies files
within the Windows partition.

It should have no effect on GRUB, which is not installed in this partition.

An image backup of your Windows disk before starting would be prudent,
but is not essential, as System Restore is basically a safe operation
(but do not interrupt it).

---

If the reason for your question is the need to recuperate
a lost administrator password, there are several methods for
doing that.

If you have a Windows boot USB you could use the
[Sticky Keys trick](https://4sysops.com/archives/forgot-the-administrator-password-the-sticky-keys-trick/)
to reset the password, without the need for System Restore.

Comment: System Restore isn't required to recover/reset the password set - there's a multitude of DOS utilities that can be booted to that can reset the passphrase for any account. The original Hiren's Boot CD had DOS utilities for this, however I haven't used the [new PE version](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) of it to know if that same utility is included within since it was slimmed down.